# Как правильно сказать - возрастной сектор?

Tags: грамотная-речь, общие-вопросы

Как правильно сказать - возрастной сектор?
Т.е. слой населения в рамках возрастной категории = возрастной уровень населения.
Срез, так сказать, общества по возрасту.
Как это сказать двумя словами - Возрастной (...) что?

Comment: @I_CaR, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Сам потом подобрал слова.  
Это: **Категория** и **Сегмент**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Категория и Сегмент
`[Минимальная длина тела 30 символов]`

Answer (score 2):

Возрастная группа, возрастной состав, люди одной возрастной ступени.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы имели в виду **возрастной ценз**. Т.е. возраст, по достижении которого можно участвовать в выборах, референдуме или занимать определенную должность.